# what's are these "@name" and "@site-name" token-things in email_example.module and how do they work?

Tags: 7, hooks, emails

In the dgo.to/example module's email_example.module's hook_mail() function there's this line:

```
      $message['body'][] = t('@name sent you the following message:', array('@name' => $user->name), $options);
```

I haven't seen `@thing` used that way before?  How does that work?  What convention is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the official [D8 Sanitizing Output Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/security/drupal-8-sanitizing-output).

#### From the documentation page

There are three available placeholders in Drupal 8:

- `@variable`: When the placeholder replacement value is a string or a MarkupInterface object
- `%variable`: When the placeholder replacement value is to be wrapped in em tags.
- `:variable`: When the placeholder replacement value is a URL to be used in the "href" attribute

You can [learn more about these placeholders in the FormattableMarkup::placeholderFormat() documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Render%21FormattableMarkup.php/function/FormattableMarkup%3A%3AplaceholderFormat/8.2.x).

### EDIT FOR DRUPAL 7:

See this documentation https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/localization-api/dynamic-strings-with-placeholders

The variables/tokens available for use as replacements is dependent on the context of the surrounding code and whether or not the script is called via Apache or from the command line.

Comment: Thanks... this is D7 actually (sorry I didn't specify) ...does that make this the relevant page https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/security/writing-secure-code/handle-text-in-a-secure-fashion ?

Comment: How do we know what placeholders are available?

Comment: see my updated answer for D7 specifics.

Comment: awesome --- so how do I see, within a given context, what token/replacements are available?  For example, right now my current context is that these replacements are within hook_mail() implementation and drupal_mail() will be sending that email from within a form submit callback function.

Comment: there is no simple way to know.  for hook_mail find all the other hook_mail implementations by modules and see what variables they add beyond the default options. For example the webform modules adds a ton of tokens. By default the following variables are available https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7.x